# Mapfish Print rendering incorrect Scalebar even with Geodetic setting

Tags: scale-bar, mapfish, mapfish-print

I'm trying to add a scalebar to my Mapfish Print pdf output but it's always rendering too small.

I have seen a few solutions that suggest using the `"geodetic": true` setting in my requests, but this makes no difference to the results.

Here's a section of the pdf output demonstrating the issue:

[image]

The blue grid marked 75 - 76 is 1 km in size, yet you can see that the scalebar rendered suggests this would be in excess of 1 km if used as the source of truth.

Any ideas how I may be able to get the scalebar to render correctly?

Here's an example request I'm sending to Mapfish Print:

```
{
    "layout": "A4 landscape",
    "outputFormat": "pdf",
    "geodetic": true,
    "attributes": {
        "map": {
            "projection": "EPSG:3857",
            "dpi": 300,
            "rotation": 0,
            "areaOfInterest": {
                "display": "NONE",
                "area": {
                    "type": "MultiPoint",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            19092823.11,
                            -5325062.01
                        ],
                        [
                            19087166.77,
                            -5329055.85
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            },
            "layers": [
                {
                    "baseURL": "http://tiles-a.data-cdn.linz.govt.nz/services;key=SECRET/tiles/v4/layer=50767/EPSG:3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                    "type": "OSM"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And the following is my config.yaml:

```
templates:
  #===========================================================================
  A4 landscape: !template
  #===========================================================================
    reportTemplate: A4-landscape.jrxml
    attributes:
      map: !map
        maxDpi: 300
        width: 802
        height: 520
      overlayLayers: !staticLayers
        default:
          layers:
            - type: "grid"
              numberOfLines: [10, 10]
              labelColor: rgba(0,0,0,0)
              haloColor: rgba(0,0,0,0)
      scalebar: !scalebar
        width: 230
        height: 35
      northArrow: !northArrow
        size: 35
        default:
          graphic: 'north.svg'
    processors:
    - !addBackgroundLayers
      inputMapper:
          overlayLayers: staticLayers
          map: map
    - !reportBuilder # compile all reports in current directory
      directory: '.'
    - !createMap {}
    - !createScalebar {}
    - !createNorthArrow {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's an open bug regarding this issue:

https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish-print/issues/327